# Swing : Jtree get all selected nodes with same hierarchy

Tags: xpath, duplicates, jtree

I am having a Jtree which is build from a xml.

My requirement is that, the user can select multiple nodes in the jtree at once and then on a click of a button, I need to get the XPaths of all the selected nodes.

For example, if the Xml is the following

```
Root
       |
       Parent
               |
             Child
               |
             Child
```

And I select both the child nodes in the jtree and then click on the button I should get [Root,  Parent, **Child1**] [Root,  Parent, **Child2**].

I have tried two ways to achieve this and both of them didn't work.

In my first attempt, I used tree.getSelectedPaths() and I was able to get the selected nodes but my problem is with the multiple nodes it gives me
[[Root,  Parent, Child], [Root,  Parent, Child]].

I require the output to be [Root,  Parent, **Child1**] [Root,  Parent, **Child2**] which will equate to 
XPath : /Root/Parent/Child1 
and /Root/Parent/Child2

In my second attempt, I also tried using the mouseListener to the tree and used the tree.getPathForLocation(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()) but in case of multiple selection, out of the 2 nodes selected, it always gives me the first node which was selected.

Please can you help me out with this even if there is an alternate approach to get the XPath for the selected nodes it would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.